# It is + inverted clause

Tags: cleft-constructions

The sentence in question:

> It is in chaos do we find reality.

I wouldn't have posted this question if the sentence were worded like this:

> We find reality in chaos.

or

> In chaos (do) we find reality.

But the construct of the original sentence, which is a cleft sentence whose complement clause is inverted, seems new to me and I'm not sure if it's grammatical (although my ears say it is). **So, is it grammatical?**

Comment: Not to my non-native ears. I keep wanting to correct that sentence to “It is in chaos that we find reality”. Where did you find it?

Comment: @Gilles: That's a nice one. The sentence was posted by a friend on Facebook.

Comment: It doesn't even sound grammatical to my native ears, I agree with Gilles.

Comment: @Gilles is correct. You need the relative pronoun *that* to precede the relative clause *do we find reality*.

Comment: It has a nice sound to it, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is off. You need *that* in this case. *Do* is only needed for emphasis. You've also got it phrased as a question.

It is in chaos that we ***do*** find reality. *Do* is an emphatic here.

-or-

It is [only] in chaos ***that*** we [do] find reality.

-or-

It is in chaos ***that*** we [do] find reality.